# Slack integration only works on onPrepare, but not in onComplete, afterLaunch?

Tags: selenium, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests, slack

I am hooking my protractor tests with Slack, the idea is to send a message on a slack room if the test started and once it's done.

However, I can only successfully send messages to slack during onPrepare. But not in afterLanch or even in onComplete.

I tried to do a simple console.log in the afterLaunch and onComplete so I know it works. The only thing that's confusing me is why it does not send the message in slack AFTER the test is done.

If there is a better way of doing this, please tell me your ideas. Right now, this is the best i've got.

Please see my code:

```
let SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;
var webRep = require('jasmine-slack-reporter');
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
var SlackWebhook = require('slack-webhook');
var slack = new SlackWebhook('my-webhook-url');

exports.config = {

capabilities: {
    'browserName' : 'chrome',
},
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4446/wd/hub',
specs: ['./smoke-test/loginAccountType.js'],

onPrepare: function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true,
    slack.send({
    text: "Test is starting",
    channel: '#test-report'
  }),
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
    spec: {
      displayStacktrace: true
    }
  })),
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
    new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
      savePath: './reports',
      takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true,
    })
  );
},

afterLaunch: function () {
  slack.send({
    text: "Test is Done",
    channel: '#test-report'
  })
},

jasmineNodeOpts: {
  // Default time to wait in ms before a test fails.
  defaultTimeoutInterval: 100000,
  print: function() {},
  },
```

};

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `slack.send()` is async?
Try to return promise from your afterLanch/onComplete - in this case protractor will wait for this promise to resolve before killing node.js process.

I never worked with `slack-webhook` package. But what i see in documentation - `.send()` is returning promise. Try to return it from your afterLaunch/onComplete:

```
afterLaunch: function () {
  return slack.send({
    text: "Test is Done",
    channel: '#test-report'
  })
},
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Xotabu4 his answer.

According to the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slack-webhook) the `send` is async, so do a `return`;

But also `catch` the error, just to check what fails, see below.

```js
return slack.send('some text')
  .then(function(res) {
    // succesful request 
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    // handle request error 
  })
```

Hope it helps